# How to distinguish between gold, silver, and bronze tag badges on SEDE?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, badges, data-explorer

How can I distinguish between the levels of [badges for a particular tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68395), say [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), querying [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)?

For example, Mr. Jon Skeet has all the gold, silver and bronze badges for LINQ, so the query

```
select *
from Badges b with (nolock)
where
    b.Name = 'linq'
and b.UserId = 22656
```

returns 3, with no distinction between them.

Is it possible to include such information into the dump, for example, keep a unique badge ID (40 for the gold [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) badge)?

Comment: You can deduce that he earned the bronze badge first and the gold one last.

Comment: But yeah, currently there's no distinction between them in the datadump.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Badges table now has a column named `Class`, which is enumerated as follows:

- 1: Gold
- 2: Silver
- 3: Bronze

Here are some example queries:

- [First User to get a Bronze Tag-Based Badge - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/560552/first-user-to-get-a-bronze-tag-based-badge)
- [First User to get a Silver Tag-Based Badge - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/560551/first-user-to-get-a-silver-tag-based-badge)
- [First User to get a Gold Tag-Based Badge - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/560550/first-user-to-get-a-gold-tag-based-badge)
- [Users with their own Bronze Tag Badges - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/559297/users-with-their-own-bronze-tag-badges)
- [Users with their own Silver Tag Badges - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/559288/users-with-their-own-silver-tag-badges)
- [Users with their own Gold Tag Badges - Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/559285/users-with-their-own-gold-tag-badges)